# Android App getSpeed() inaccurate on slowdown

Tags: android, gps

sorry if this is covered somewhere else but I was unable to find this problem specifically.

I am developing a racing app for someone that tells you how many seconds ahead or behind you are based upon a preset target speed.

To test it, we are using an onboard computer that reads the speed directly from the car(no GPS). My app appears to match the onboard computer somewhat until the car begins to slow down and then my app becomes erratic.

Here is a video with the problem appearing at about 1:38
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhVM1VCqiA8

The fact that the app is spot on at times lends me to believe that the GPS coverage and the formula for computing the time are fine.

Clearly there are accuracy problems especially when the car slows down.

Here is some of my code for tracking the speed.

```
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener

{

    @Override

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)

    {

        actualSpeedMps = (double)loc.getSpeed();

    }
////more
```

I am thinking that the GPS is trying to update too quickly, thus giving me erratic speeds when the car makes a sudden change.

My thought was to change the requestLocationUpdates minimum time parameter which is currently 0 to something like 500.

I took this class from a basic tutorial so maybe someone can refer me to a more accurate one that can get me a better speed.

thanks in advance

Comment: This looks  wrong. Describle please what units are visible in the video. Is this mile per /h ? Where is the speed in the red cars display? top or lower  red display? What does your app display? Your app in most cases display the half value. You could also compare with a Navi or a GPS App which works. On harsh breaking, of course GPS will be off 1 second. But you have other problems, at leat in the video

Comment: My app displays how many seconds ahead or behind you are compared to your target speed. The number should match up with the top number of the onboard computer(right), which it does at first before becoming inaccurate.

Comment: What is the target speed? GPS measures current speed, and this very correct (0.1 km/h). In your question you describe current speed, but now you tell target speed. Explain more detailed and and more precise what exactly you want to measure. How is target sped defined, what is the unizt of target speed, Where does the target speed come from?

Comment: About slow down. How many m/s or km/h is the car driving when you say "slow down" ?

Comment: Is this for an "average speed" race where the goal is to reach the destination with an exact average Speed? Dont you need distance calculation for this, too?

Comment: For example if you set the target speed to '60mph' and then drive at 30mph. After 1 min the clock will show you are about at -30sec(behind your target speed). In the video, the target speed is 30mph and the driver drives slightly above 30mph so both clocks show a few seconds ahead.

Comment: At which speed (mph) you get the problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The fact that the app is spot on at times lends me to believe that the
>   GPS coverage and the formula for computing the time are fine.

Often your value is double or tripple the value of the red device.
And that when you are driving around 30 m/h.
GPS is super acurate at medium and high speeds (like in vehicles)

So the problem is clearly in your algorithm and in asumptions when you get a GPS position.

> I am thinking that the GPS is trying to update too quickly, thus
>   giving me erratic speeds when the car makes a sudden change.

For sure not, It will not update more than once a second.
You get problems with GPs only when standing still, then it does often not report 0 km/h, but this is another story.

**Conclusion:**
The GPS is not the source of the error, it's your algorithm.

Tipps:

- Try to fix your algorithm, by writing a unit test with simulated GPS
  inputs
- Do not asume you receive a location once a second, use the timestamps to calculate the time difference
- Record your locations into a file, if you dont trust the speed values, calculate them using the distance between two locations  divide by seconds between them, then you see  that they are correct.
    And input that recorded locations to your test case, and debug where you got the negative values.
- Try to write more precisly down what you want to achieve: How do you define " I am 10 secons behind": e.g "behind a car that would have driven with target speed."
- Think if you need to record the distance driven, then your app can make it better then the red-letter-device, which cannot measure
  distance so good.

Comment: Thanks for your input, can you point me toward a good GPS class code example that I could use to get the speed just to make sure thats not the problem? I'm working on changing my app to simulate speeds to try and narrow down the problem with my algorithm.

Comment: if the gps speed is above 2m/s it is acurate. first solve your algo, then handlw the special case when vehicle is stopped and gps till shows 1m/s.